# For loop/Functions Logical Error in Displaying Values

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, for-loop, logic

I am rather new to Python 3.x and am running into a logical error with my functions while trying to display them in a table format.

```
#Main Function:

def main():
    LuInvest()
    LeInvest()
    dispT()

#Function 1

def LeInvest():
    for year in range (1,28):
        LeGain = (100 * .1)
        LeTotal = (100 + (LeGain * year))
    return LeTotal

#Function 2

def LuInvest():
    for year in range( 1,28):
       LuTotal = (100 * ( 1 + .05 ) ** year)
    return LuTotal

#Display Function

def dispT():
    print ("Year:\tLeia's Investment\tLuke's Investment")
    for year in range (1,28):
        print ('%i\t    %.2f\t\t     %.2f' %(year, LeInvest(),LuInvest()))
```

What gets displayed is:

```
Year:       Leia's Investment       Luke's Investment
1               370.00                   373.35
2               370.00                   373.35
3               370.00                   373.35
```

If I insert a `print` statement within Function 1 & 2 then remove `dispT()` from the main function, it will display all of the correct values over the years, but not in the correct format. If I use `dispT()` it will only show the final amount for Function 1 & 2's `range` (as shown above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `dispT` function, uyou call the `LeInvest` (and `LuInvest`) function many times. But there is no reason why they should return different values! Even on the first call (in year 1) to `LeInvest`, this function looks through 27 years.

Within the `LeInvest` function, you probably don't want to loop in `range(1,28)`, but through something like `range(1, maxyear)`, where maxyear is a parameter to the function.

E.g.:

```
def LeInvest(maxyear):
    for year in range (1,maxyear):
        LeGain = (100 * .1)
        LeTotal = (100 + (LeGain * year))
    return LeTotal

# TODO: Similar for LuInvest

def dispT():
    print ("Year:\tLeia's Investment\tLuke's Investment")
    for year in range (1,28):
        print ('%i\t    %.2f\t\t     %.2f' %(year, LeInvest(year),LuInvest(year)))
```